# Angular - Understanding the handleError function of Tour of Heroes

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm reading this tutorial:
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#error-handling

I cannot totally understand the `error-handling` with the function: `handleError`.

That function is used on this code snippet:

```
/** GET heroes from the server */
getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
    .pipe(
      tap(heroes => this.log(`fetched heroes`)),
      catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
    );
}
```

here is the `handleError` function:

```
/**
 * Handle Http operation that failed.
 * Let the app continue.
 * @param operation - name of the operation that failed
 * @param result - optional value to return as the observable result
 */
private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
  return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

    // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
    console.error(error); // log to console instead

    // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
    this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

    // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
    return of(result as T);
  };
}
```

I don't understand what means:

`return (error: any): Observable<T> => { ... }`?

is that something similar to:

`return ((error: any): Observable<T>) => { ... }`?

I just want to know what's the source and the destiny of the function.

The more details you can provide about the logic of `handleError` function, the better. I want to go deep on this.

Comment: Those parts of the code that you cited, I can't understand either. I hope an expert will explain them. I did use the handleError function in my app. It worked good for me. I called it from each of my http call methods. The last line  return of(result as T);  sends a substitute  Observable to stand in for the response that would have been returned had not there been an error.

Comment: I think this answer covered what you asked:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52471630/10291121

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parentheses are optional when there's only one parameter name, you can see more detail from [arrow_functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Syntax)

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements } 
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
// equivalent to: => { return expression; } 

// Parentheses are optional when there's only one parameter name:
(singleParam) => { statements }
singleParam => { statements }

// The parameter list for a function with no parameters should be written with a pair of parentheses.
() => { statements }
```

---

**Generic**

this  allows us to capture the type the user provides, it's a type check way of Typescript, you can call it one of the multiple ways.

reference

- [Typescript Generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

---

in this example, we use T again as the return type. On inspection, we can now see the type is used for the return type

```
private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
  return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

    ...

    return of(result as T);
  };
}
```

---

below example, I will explain Generic how to work with `string` and `number` type

```js
// string type (maybe you want to return some mesage when error)
getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
    .pipe(
      ...
      catchError(this.handleError<string>('getHeroes', 'my result....'))
    );
}
// similar to : private handleError<number>(operation = 'operation', result ? : number)
//  return (error: any): Observable <number> => { ...
private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result? : T) {
  return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

    ...

    // result: my result....
    return of(result);
  };
}


----

// number type (maybe you want to return ID:1234) when error
getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
    .pipe(
      ...
      catchError(this.handleError<string>('getHeroes', '1234'))
    );
}
// similar to : private handleError<string>(operation = 'operation', result ? : string) 
//  return (error: any): Observable <string> => { ...
private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result? : T) {
  return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

    ...

    // reuslt: 1234
    return of(result);
  };
}
```

Comment: I already knew about what you pointed out, but I want to know about the Generics, also some explanation with the concrete example I posted above. Thanks!