# Angular RXJS CatchError in Heroes tutorial

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm running the Angular tutorial and I can't understand what is actually happening in one section. I've found some examples from searching, but nothing specifically answers this question. Here is the code:

```
getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
    );
}
```

Next is the error handler it calls:

```
/**
 * Handle Http operation that failed.
 * Let the app continue.
 * @param operation - name of the operation that failed
 * @param result - optional value to return as the observable result
 */
private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
  return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

    // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
    console.error(error); // log to console instead

    // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
    this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

    // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
    return of(result as T);
  };
}
```

I read the documentation I could find on catchError. I'm new to Typescript and really enjoying it though. Okay, so the question is why I'm passing a function to catchError, which then returns another function. Specifically, my question is about the embedded function `return (error: any): Observable<T> => {`

Why is handleError returning a function with fat arrow notation instead of just an observable of type T? How is the error parameter of the embedded function receiving data?

I think it has something to do with the fact that handleError is called, which returns a function. So in essence catchError receives that embedded function with the parameter error, but it also has the variables `operation` and `result?` in the same scope so it can work with those. catchError then passes the data to the parameter error and returns an observable T.

RXJS Reference defines catchError as:

```
catchError<T, R>(selector: (err: any, caught: Observable<T>) =>
ObservableInput<R>): OperatorFunction<T, T | R>
```

But it's hard for me to decipher why it's being passed a function as all the example have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct: the `handleError` function gets called first which itself creates a function for handling the error. There are a couple of other ways to write this that might help clarify a bit more:

```
// write the function inline:
catchError(error => {
  console.error(error);
  this.log(`getHeroes failed: ${error.message}`);
  return of([]);
});

// call `handleError` first to get the error handler and pass it as a variable.
const errorHandler = this.handleError('getHeroes', []);
return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
  .pipe(catchError(errorHandler));
```

`catchError` requires a *function* passed to it that returns an Observable to continue the observable stream. The returned observable is created by `of`. The type T allows the error handler to determine the type of the values emitted by the Observable based on the fallback argument you've passed in.