# Having trouble understanding Angular error handler

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having trouble understanding how the following error handler works and, more specifically, why it's returning a function:

```
  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error);
      this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }
```

Why is it written the way it is above and not:

```
  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T, error?: any): Observable<T> {
      console.error(error);
      this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);
      return of(result as T);
  }
```

I tried rewriting it in my code and I get the following error:

```
Argument of type 'Observable<Hero[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<Hero[]>) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'Observable<Hero[]>' provides no match for the signature '(err: any, caught: Observable<Hero[]>): ObservableInput<any>'.ts(2345)
```

But I'm not sure what it means. My understanding is it's adding extra props on top of the expected function type that the `catchError` hook needs.

This is all provided code from [the Angular docs](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt6#error-handling), but here's the `Hero` type:

```
export interface Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

and how I call the `handleError` function:

```
  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl).pipe(
      tap((_) => this.log(`fetched heroes`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('getHeroes', []))
    );
  }
```

Comment: It's a higher-order function, a function _returning a function_, simply because `catchError` takes a function. Hence the error when you don't return a function, which tells you the same thing - an Observable is not a function. Also discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50997081/3001761. _"Instead of handling the error directly, **it returns an error handler function to `catchError`**. This function is configured with both the name of the operation that failed and a safe return value."_

Comment: So the purpose of this higher-order fn is simply to handle the error in a generic way and make sure it doesn't break the code by returning something safe. Without it, the catchError would default to breaking the code?

Comment: That's the purpose of the function it returns, the purpose of the higher-order function is to _create that function_ for a given set of inputs. _"The following `handleError()` can be shared by many `HeroService` methods so it's generalized to meet their different needs."_ Without it `catchError` _wouldn't have an argument at all_, which I think is invalid. Here's a simpler example where the `handlerError` method is used directly: https://angular.io/guide/http-handle-request-errors#getting-error-details.